# Jmeter console manipulation for automation purposes

Tags: console, jmeter

I am pretty newbie by this question.

I want to know about possibilities of how to manipulate Jmeter through the console (bash or cmd).

My goal for a start consists in understanding of how to run my testplan.jmx for several URLS. For this I add "server" and "port" parameters into my testplan.

How could I can change these parameters through the console and then run Jmeter ?

Morover, I want to ask you guys to suggest any free online tutorials where I can learn more about "Jmeter in non gui mode" and possibilities for integration Jmeter between different frameworks to use for automated testing.

Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:
http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/How-to-Run-Jmeter-in-command-line-td2640725.html

You can launch your test plan from the command line, specifying parameters, like:
jmeter -n -t plan.jmx -Jmy_url=http://www.firsturl.com

Inside your testplan you'd reference that command line param as ${__P(my_url)}

In terms of capturing results when running in non-gui mode, you may want to see:
http://blogs.amd.com/developer/2009/03/31/using-apache-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/

Personally, my experience is with using the GUI and writing and running test plans that way but this seems workable.

Comment: Thank you, mate. It's much simplier than I thought.